# How to include header.html.twig file in page.html.twig file in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, content-management-system, drupal-8

I have page.html.twig file in drupal 8X version in that file how to include header.html.twig file which is located as includes directory in same theme directory

Answer (score 2):

The correct method for Drupal 8 themes is to use Twig namespaces to declare the current theme "templates" directory. Here is an example:

```
{% include '@THEME_NAME/includes/header.html.twig' %}
```

Below is an example taken from a working theme on Drupal.org called Architect.
"@architect" refers to /templates in the working theme (architect) directory.

```
{% include '@architect/includes/header.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: It's not working while add a twig in mentioned above shows some error like "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: "Unexpected error" is message for site visitors, not for developers. Check on some error log (Reports > Recent log messages) or enable error reporting to see what's really going on there. Maybe you are trying to include unexisting template file or something.